# Query using Group by in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table :

```
ReviewID | Author_id | Posted time
-------------------------------------
R1       | U1        | ...
R2       | U2
R3       | U2
R9       | U7
R11      | U7 
R12      | U7
R13      | U8
R14      | U10
```

My query is such that I want to get U7. I tried with following :

```
 select author_id 
 from posted_reviews_tab 
 group by author_id
 having (count(author_id)) in (
        select max(count(author_id)) 
        from posted_reviews_tab   
        where reviewid in ( 
             select w.reviews.reviewid 
             from wall_tab w  
             where w.shopid = 'S9' 
        ) 
        group by author_id
);
```

shop s9 has 4 reviews R11,R12,R13,R14 on its wall. The above table shows which user posted which review. From my wall table , I come to know  which shop has which all reviews written on its wall. So, once I get all the reviews, I want to find out the user who posted most number of reviews (which is U7)
Above query gives me U2 since the max count is 2.(2 becoz u7 post R11 and R12 )Can anyone suggest a workaround ?

Comment: why you have used `max(count(author_id))`?? Doesn't make any sense to me..

Comment: So what exactly do you want in English? Do you just want the authorID with the most reviews from shopID s9? or what?

Comment: Yes , the authorID of user who posted most reviews from shopID s9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets you U7, but I'm not sure I understood your requirement for limiting the result to a specific shop.

```
select author_id,
       cnt
from (
   select author_id, 
          count(*) cnt,
          rank() over (order by count(*) desc) as rnk
   from posted_reviews_tab
   group by author_id
) t
where rnk = 1;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/52d62/1

Comment: This seems like the solution. Did not know about rank(). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I undeerstood the question, this is what you want..

```
select author_id from posted_reviews_tab group by author_id
 having (count(author_id)) in (

 select max(author_id) from posted_reviews_tab   
 where reviewid in ( 
 select w.reviews.reviewid from wall_tab w  where w.shopid = 'S9' 
 ) 
 group by author_id
  );
```

Comment: `count(author_id) in (select max(author_id) ... )` won't work, as `max(author_id)` returns `'U10'` which cannot be compared to a numeric value.